# Delegate for LINQ Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates, anonymous-function

In my codebase, I have a large number of classes that need to perform various collective operations on their members to get results (average, standard deviation, confidence intervals etc.)

The `Average` LINQ Extension method already exists, but `StandardDeviation` does not, so I implemented it as follows:

```
public static double StandardDeviation<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, double> selector)
{
    var average = source.Average(selector);
    var sumOfSquares = source.Sum(sample => Math.Pow(selector(sample) - average, 2));
    return Math.Pow(sumOfSquares, 0.5);
}
```

I'd like to find a way to define a delegate for this function, ideally as a LINQ extension, to avoid duplicate code. Below is an example of current usage of the two methods:

```
    public override void Average(IList<ThisType> samples)
    {
        TotalEntered = samples.Average(sample => sample.TotalEntered);
        TotalExited = samples.Average(sample => sample.TotalExited);
        MinimumContents = samples.Average(sample => sample.MinimumContents);
        AverageContents = samples.Average(sample => sample.AverageContents);
        MaximumContents = samples.Average(sample => sample.MaximumContents);
        MinimumTime = samples.Average(sample => sample.MinimumTime);
        AverageTime = samples.Average(sample => sample.AverageTime);
        MaximumTime = samples.Average(sample => sample.MaximumTime);
        StdDevTime = samples.Average(sample => sample.StdDevTime);
        AverageNonZeroTime = samples.Average(sample => sample.AverageNonZeroTime);
        PercentageWithinLimit = samples.Average(sample => sample.PercentageWithinLimit);
        base.Average(samples);
    }

    public override void StandardDeviation(IList<ThisType> samples)
    {
        TotalEntered = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.TotalEntered);
        TotalExited = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.TotalExited);
        MinimumContents = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.MinimumContents);
        AverageContents = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.AverageContents);
        MaximumContents = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.MaximumContents);
        MinimumTime = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.MinimumTime);
        AverageTime = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.AverageTime);
        MaximumTime = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.MaximumTime);
        StdDevTime = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.StdDevTime);
        AverageNonZeroTime = samples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.AverageNonZeroTime);
        PercentageWithinLimit = queueSamples.StandardDeviation(sample => sample.PercentageWithinLimit);
        base.StandardDeviation(samples);
    }
```

I tried to create a delegate for these methods, as follows:

```
public delegate double CollectiveOperation<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, double> selector);
```

To be used in the following replacement for the above near-duplication of code:

```
    public void Operation(IList<ThisType> samples, LINQExtensions.CollectiveOperation<ThisType> Operation)
    {
        BufferMinimumTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.BufferMinimumTime);
        BufferAverageTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.BufferAverageTime);
        BufferMaximumTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.BufferMaximumTime);
        BufferStdDevTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.BufferStdDevTime);
        TotalMinimumTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.TotalMinimumTime);
        TotalAverageTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.TotalAverageTime);
        TotalMaximumTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.TotalMaximumTime);
        TotalStdDevTime = samples.Operation(sample => sample.TotalStdDevTime);
        base.Operation(samples);
    }
```

However, I wasn't able to call `Average` or `StandardDeviation` through these delegates, presumably because of the `this` keyword. Upon removing this from the `StandardDeviation` implementation and replacing the calls with something like:

```
BufferMinimumTime = Operation(samples, sample => sample.BufferMinimumTime);
```

It still wouldn't fit with the delegate, producing the following error message:

```
Expected a method with 'double StandardDeviation(IEnumerable<ThisType>, Func<ThisType, double>)' signature.
```

Is there any way for me to create a delegate for a generic, static LINQ extension as above? These methods will be used in a variety of classes in unique ways, so they must be generic.

Comment: I managed to get this to work with your definitions of `CollectiveOperation<T>` and `StandardDeviation<T>`, stock `Enumerable.Average<T>` and a small test class for `T`. Can you condense your question to an example with the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: first your `StandardDeviation` extension should be using yield returns and not full collection return, look on the web for that. Secondly you can use reflection and get the list of member in sample where name matches a local member and then call the average method assigning the result to the local member.

Comment: @Franck How can `StandardDeviation` use `yield return` when it only needs to return a single value, not a sequence?

Comment: Oh i see what you mean but seeing that he need to call that list like 12 times in a row that is an iteration to me that could easily be in the method as a list and return the same list calculated.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me a little bit of MapReduce. You have a collection of objects you want to map (e.g. select a single property of the object) to a numeric value and after that you want to reduce this new collection of numeric values to a single numeric value. You could define a Wrapper-Method (for easier use):

```
    public static TResult MapReduce<T, TMap, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TMap> mapper, Func<IEnumerable<TMap>, TResult> reducer)
    {
        return reducer(source.Select(mapper));
    }
```

Define `Operation`-Method as follows:

```
    public void Operation(IEnumerable<TestClass> samples, Func<IEnumerable<double>, double> operation)
    {
        var foo = samples.MapReduce(s => s.Foo, operation);
        var bar = samples.MapReduce(s => s.Bar, operation);
    }
```

And call it with:

```
        this.Operation(new List<TestClass>(), Enumerable.Average);
        this.Operation(new List<TestClass>(), MyLinqExtensions.StandardDeviation);
```

But you have to implement your `StandardDeviation` a little bit different:

```
    internal static double StandardDeviation(this IEnumerable<double> source)
    {
        var average = source.Average();
        var sumOfSquares = source.Sum(sample => Math.Pow(sample - average, 2));
        return Math.Pow(sumOfSquares, 0.5);
    }
```